# OPA (Rego) as Go lib: How to apply external data?

Tags: go, open-policy-agent, rego

I followed the example of https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/#5-try-opa-as-a-go-library. Important code snippets:

```
r := rego.New(
rego.Query("x = data.example.allow"),
rego.Load([]string{"./example.rego"}, nil)
...
rs, err := query.Eval(ctx, rego.EvalInput(input))
...
```

How can I add external data (`data.json`) such that I can use, e.g., `data.wantedName` in the rego policy to access it?

I tried to read through the go doc and the examples but I couldn't find any helpful information.

Thanks!

Comment: There are many ways to load data into OPA, I suggest you take a look here to review them and choose the best for your use case https://dev.to/permit_io/load-external-data-into-opa-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-26lc

Answer (score 7):

Have you seen the docs on [`rego.Store()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/open-policy-agent/opa@v0.33.1/rego#Store) and [this example](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/open-policy-agent/opa@v0.33.1/rego#example-Rego.Eval-Storage)?

Something along these lines should do the trick for simple cases:

```golang
    data := `{
        "example": {
            "users": [
                {
                    "name": "alice",
                    "likes": ["dogs", "clouds"]
                },
                {
                    "name": "bob",
                    "likes": ["pizza", "cats"]
                }
            ]
        }
    }`

    var json map[string]interface{}

    err := util.UnmarshalJSON([]byte(data), &json)
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error.
    }

    store := inmem.NewFromObject(json)

    // Create new query that returns the value
    rego := rego.New(
        rego.Query("data.example.users[0].likes"),
        rego.Store(store))
```

You could implement your own storage for more intricate uses, but that's going to be a lot more involved. If you get by with feeding `inmem.NewFromObject()` stores into `rego.New()`, you should try that first.

Comment: In addition to this answer, one might want to check out the new SDK: https://blog.styra.com/blog/the-open-policy-agent-sdk-overview

Comment: @sr_ Yes, I tried that but I load the policy (`rego.policy`) in `rego.New` as well. I don't know how to combine both of them into the `rego.New` statement.

Comment: @Devoops thanks for that link! As I followed some links in this article I come across the ability to use `bundles` and now I see I can use bundles in the go lib as well. I will look into that.

Comment: @bogg yeah, it essentially allows you to run OPA as if you would be running from the command line, with config file and all that goodness :)